# Is web-animations-api abandoned?

Tags: javascript, web-animations

I've been interested in implementing animations in JavaScript recently, and I've been interested in waapi.

So I studied the relevant parts and there were too many problems. First, there was virtually no support in the browser, and second, development of the polyfill library was stopped.

I wonder if this api is actually going to be deprecated.

Comment: No, it's a [working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations/).

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations/ Working Drafts are early versions of a specification. It can take years to get to Recommendation and along the way, anything can happen.

Comment: There's a very recent [specification draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations/) for it, but that's no guarantee that it'll be implemented everywhere (or even soon, unfortunately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API is supported in Firefox and Chrome. However, only a portion of the API is available in the current release versions of these browsers.

The remainder of the API is available in the Firefox Nightly / Chrome Canary builds of these browsers although you may need to [enable experimental Web platform features in Chrome](https://css-irl.info/how-to-enable-experimental-web-platform-features/) to make use of them. The Firefox implementation is nearly 100% complete and is currently waiting for Chrome and Safari implementations to reach parity before shipping.

Support in Safari is good but currently only available in Technology Preview builds. The release date is unclear as Safari do not always announce their future release plans.

As you note, however, the polyfill is not actively maintained since native support in browsers has progressed so far now. For many cases, it may be acceptable to serve older browsers that do not support Web Animations the un-animated version that would also be served to users who have indicated they would [prefer reduced motion](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion).